iOS17 WidgetKit Multiple Widget Instances Repeatedly Pointing to the Same Data Issue
I am developing an iOS 17 Widget that allows users to check-in for their Thing objects.
I encountered a strange issue while using WidgetKit and the AppIntents framework.
When I create multiple Widget instances simultaneously, clicking any of the Widget instances to check-in always updates the first Thing. It seems that multiple Widget instances are repeatedly pointing to the same Thing.
For example, I have two things: Run, Pill. I created two widget instances on the screen, each corresponding to one of these things. However, no matter which widget instance I click, it always updates the check-in for Run, instead of the corresponding thing for the widget instance clicked.
I have reviewed the official documentation and watched several tutorials, but I still cannot eliminate this bug on the simulator.
Here is the relevant code snippet:
I am using Core Data as the storage solution, and I have created a wrapper structure called ThingData for my Core Data entities:
struct ThingData: Codable, AppEntity {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String?
    ...
}

struct ConfigurationAppIntent: WidgetConfigurationIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Select Thing"
    static var description = IntentDescription("Choose a thing to display in the widget.")

    @Parameter(title:"Select thing")
    var thing: ThingData
    
    init(thing: ThingData) {
        self.thing = thing
    }
    
    init(){
        
    }

    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        // Strangely, our print statement always outputs the Run thing
        // even when checking in through the Pill widget.
        print("perform thing: \(thing)")
        let context = PersistenceController.shared.viewContext
        if let fetchedThing = fetchThing(by: thing.id, context: context){
            // execute check in
            viewModel.checkIn(fetchedThing)
        }
        return .result()
    }

    private func fetchThing(by id: UUID, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Thing? {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Thing> = Thing.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id as CVarArg)
        return try? context.fetch(fetchRequest).first
    }
}

And there is EntityQuery:
struct ThingDataQuery: EntityQuery {
    func entities(for identifiers: [UUID]) async throws -> [ThingData] {
        let context = PersistenceController.shared.viewContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Thing> = Thing.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", identifiers)

        do {
            let things = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return things.map { $0.toThingData() }
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }
    
    func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [ThingData] {
        let context = PersistenceController.shared.viewContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Thing> = Thing.fetchRequest()

        do {
            let things = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return things.map { $0.toThingData() }
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }
    
    func defaultResult() async -> ThingData? {
        let context = PersistenceController.shared.viewContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Thing> = Thing.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1

        do {
            let things = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return things.first?.toThingData()
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

In the provider, I am using configuration.thing without re-fetching the thing.
this is my widget, you can see that they show the different thing
I have read the official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/making-a-configurable-widget and watched several YouTube tutorials, but none have solved my problem. I want my widget to correctly interact with the thing selected by the user, rather than always pointing to a single thing.
